# transaction error when sending Nexo with metamask

Tags: transactions, metamask, gas

[image][image]trying to send Nexo from Metamask wallet to HitBtc exchange. After waiting, the system issues a transaction error, and the ETH commission is debited from the account. Accidentally sent an empty transaction 0 to Nexo and it went through. But when sending the maximum amount of Nexo, the transaction does not go through and gives an error.

Comment: You are sending ethers to a token contract that doesn't accept ether payments. You should check that you are sending the ethers to the correct address.

Comment: @Ismael♦ The address seems to be in order, and a transaction with a zero value went to this address, what's the matter?

Comment: The contract doesn't have a fallback function, so any transfer of a value other than zero will revert.